# How is this 3D rendering on the desktop done

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, rendering, transparent

I read a topic on OpenGL.org where a guy made this:
http://coreytabaka.com/programming/cube-demo/

He said to release the source code but he never did,
does anyone how I could get the same idea?

Has to do with clearing the window with alpha but drawing
on it as well.. just don't get how to get OpenGL setup like
that. From there I can do my stuff but I'd like a base for
this running in C++ with VisualStudio,

Anybody has something like this laying around ? Or can show
pieces of the code to get this kind of rendering done.

Comment: I think its dependent on the OS. You should specify which operating system you want.

Comment: I hope I didn't just install some malware on my computer.

Comment: thyrgle: If you read the question it should be apparent that he's looking to do it on Windows.

Comment: Indeed I want it to run on Windows, same as the application I showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Render the 3d scene to a pbuffer.
2. Use a color key to blend the pbuffer to screen.